# How to mount novell share?

Tags: mount

I would like to mount netWare service on my linux.
Could someone give me example how such a line should looks like in fstab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the directions [here](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/trench/16445.html),

**EXAMPLE:**

1) Verify the installation of ncpfs:

```
linux~# rpm -q
ncpfs-2.6.6-7
```

2) Create a mountpoint for the server

```
linux~# mkdir /mnt/myserver
```

3) Create a group to assign the filerights to

```
linux~# groupadd nwaccess
```

4) Assign users to the defined group

```
linux~# usermod -G nwaccess veerh01
```

5) Create a password file

```
linux~# echo myserver/myuser.location.nds:mypassword >/etc/ncp-pass
linux~# chmod 600 /etc/ncp-pass
```

6) create a mount line in /etc/fstab - that is edit /etc/fstab with your favorite editor and add a line to it with the following definitions:

```
<server/user> <mountpoint> ncp uid=root,gid=<group>,mode=660,owner=root,A=<server>,passwdfile=/etc/ncp-pass     0 0
```

For the example described above it becomes:

```
myserver/myuser.location.nds /mnt/myserver ncp uid=root,group=nwaccess,mode=660,owner=root,A=myserver,passwdfile=/etc/ncp-pass 0 0
```

Comment: My share looks like this: \\SMTH\SMT\SMT and there's no user. On windows machine I see this share on my J drive. I usnderstand that I need ncpfs but still don't know how that fstab line should looks like in my case.

Comment: If you don't need to actually read and write the files, why do you need the share? If you do need to read and write the files, you need a user.

Comment: humm I guess you right, so I could use the same user which Im using when login to novel network on my windows pc. So lets say my user name is test and my password is stored in that ncp-pass file. How this line shoould looks now?

Comment: Also, it's so your Linux user has permissions to the filesystem once mounted.

Comment: Ok after few tries I finally understand this and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We (still) run a mixed back of netware and OES servers.

To attach to the netware servers we tell our users to use the following cifs command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //NETWARESERVER/VOLUMENAME /mount/point/ -o username=USERNAME,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm
```

The most important part in that is the `sec=ntlm` since netware is running an earlier version of cifs.

To attach to OES servers we tell the users to run the same command, but without the `sec-ntlm` option.

If you're adding this to fstab  I think you would need to also add a `password=PASSWORD` to the options too.

Hope that helps.